# Build to a Windows Server

Tags: jenkins, deployment, windows-server-2008

I'm using Jenkins to build my WAR/EAR to a windows server.Everything works fine.i.e I can push my files on the server using my username,But what I want is to Create a group so that everyone in that group can push the code into the server not only me, In case I leave the organisation then the above needs to be changed instead if a group is allowed then, this wont be an issue anymore.

So my question is I have a group created on the windows server with the people needed to have access,But how do I login into the server using that group or better yet how do I mention that in Jenkins so that Jenkins has access to that group.

I have heard that groups perform the same function of a application user of that of Unix (Not sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins using it's own user `jenkins` so if your issue is only to have Jenkins able to login to server, I would suggest to add user Jenkins to the group you mentioned.